# SonataAdminBundle: adding new entity issue

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've took a "new" installation of Symfony and I've integrated it with Sonata Admin Bundle.
After reading something about S.A.B. I've decide to try add myself a "category" into dashboard.
As far I know I have to:

- create my entity and table onto db (doctrine will do it for me)
- Create an Admin class for my new entity
- Register  that Admin class as a service and tag it as `sonata.admin` as requested

My problem is, substantially this:

I've follow Sonata User Bundle approach and find some classes (it came with User and Groups taken from FOSUserBundle) and define an Entity (empty) that extends a Model where code is. That model have to contain property (columns table) and getters and setters.
So I started to write that model with ***annotation*** method. This is my code:

```php
<?php

namespace Sonata\SestanteBundle\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Sonata\SestanteBundle\Model\myFooEntity;
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="myFooTable")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Sonata\SestanteBundle\Repository\myFooRepository")
 */

class myFooEntity
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
    */
    private $fooName;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
    */
    private $isActive;
}
```

Now when I run:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities vendor/bundles/Sonata/SestanteBundle/Model
```

I receive that error:

> [RuntimeException]   Namespace "vendor\bundles\Sonata\SestanteBundle\Model" does not contain any mapped entities.

What came in my mind:

- Is setted elsewhere the mapping method, force me to express that properties into .xml files like `groups` and users `does` ?
  Into `config.yml` I just see something "standard"

Any ideas for go beyond this error?

**Edit:** I suppose that problem is about namespace or something like this. If I try to generate an entity with a different name (that doesn't exists), i receive the same error...

Comment: Do you have in your config.yml something like: doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    SonataSestanteBundle: ~

Answer (score 0):

While it may be a pain, removing all the `@ORM\` in your entity, and commenting out or removing `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;` has fixed my issues with this before.  I have tried to determine what causes the namespace to be placed there and how to stop it, but without success.